# How to fix Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

When performing:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string input = client.DownloadString("https://blockchain.com/btc/address/1Q72ZCfpxcCgzxbYypVdFmuwA3yi7RLYqs");
MatchCollection matchList = Regex.Matches(input, @"\[{""txid"":""(.*)"",""size""");
textBox3.AppendText(matchList[0] + Environment.NewLine);
```

to grab the TXID parameter from the blockchain, if there are multiple transactions rather than returning multiple sets it will grab everthing between the first instance of `[{"txid"` and last instance of `"size"`
I want an output array such as `matchList[0] = first txid no`. && `matchList[1] = second txid no.` and so forth. Right now I am receiving

```
matchList[0] = [{"txid":"0ca6af3928549b977a4777924512f0665152617d2fece5e23d283d071b2beadb","size":191,"version":1,"locktime":0,"fee":11194,"inputs":[{"coinbase":false,"txid":"56273bfc7a26c544c8e13753dfc7eae83ad1f02814daef794977aa387ee427ab","output":679,"sigscript":"47304402200371a16fd5c97e534351068b51f1eff520cb48388ffd8eeeeff27263aa802f0002202ed64c87706446bb3300d4a0a7926e7e98cd72791056b9e79e9d1359619c3482012102312f378fb165556de77c3177061c2a930a14a10b72bf5c83e30f19f6d33375b4","sequence":4294967295,"pkscript":"76a9143624ef002f2d01d6414a0448e7b1af18cd0fd31288ac","value":23159,"address":"15wHjYuc3KY9kVNzkEYzrq7mG9yuQWbzhw","witness":null}],"outputs":[{"address":"1Q72ZCfpxcCgzxbYypVdFmuwA3yi7RLYqs","pkscript":"76a914fd6eafdfb79b40925b114f1dcb32e750586b119388ac","value":11965,"spent":false,"spender":null}],"block":{"height":639529,"position":2069},"deleted":false,"time":1594918670,"rbf":false,"weight":764},{"txid":"7e90a4c2e1103861291731288bd2c05198873ad05a73b9f0f40380f747160d42","size"
```

Comment: Do you know anything about `deserializing` a `json` string? You could just deserialize this into an array of objects as I imagine the response is intended to be, and then grab the `txid` of each element in the array.

Comment: @RyanWilson: It looks like he's scraping that string off a website that has the JSON string in it. The string itself isn't parseable as JSON.

Comment: Speaking of which, what you're trying to do probably isn't legal, as it's against the [terms and conditions](https://www.blockchain.com/legal/terms) for using blockchain.com: "13.2 Acceptable Use of Blockchain.com Services
When accessing or using the Services, you agree that you are solely responsible for your conduct while accessing and using our Services. Without limiting the generality of the foregoing, you agree that you shall not:...use any robot, spider, crawler, scraper or other automated means or interface not provided by us to access our Services or to extract data"

Comment: If you know of another way I can get the txid of transactions with C# I will use that but I don't know of any other way, also this is manual not automated so I am not breaking any terms of service even if it is through an application it is not scraping many addresses only this one

Comment: But, legal or not, if you get the full string, it is very likely JSON.  Parsing JSON and getting what you are looking for is easy.  Using a Regex to parse JSON is not recommended

Comment: I think deserialization will work I havent worked with C# parsing before so its a little confusing to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will match the ***taxid*** name at the beginning of the *object* `{`.
It's string *Value* is in group 1. And the name=value is followed by the ***size*** name.
*Note there is no allowance for whitespace anywhere.*

`@"{""txid"":""([^""]*?)"",""size"""`

https://regex101.com/r/OR2p2a/1

Note that if you need to parse the full JSON, partial, repair, or otherwise
using C# regex, I have a tutorial on how to do this.
*Let me know.*